# How to use <-chan and chan<- for one directional communication?

Tags: go, channel

I'm working on understanding Go's channels. I think I understand a basic bidirectional `chan` but I'm falling short at understanding `<-chan` and `chan<-`.

I expected them to be useful for communicating one way to a thread but I'm having issues with the thread actually reading and receiving the value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Thread(c chan<- int) {
    for {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan<- int, 3)
    go Thread(c)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    for len(c) > 0 {
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}
```

I've tried using `<-chan` instead of `chan<-` in the `make()` but the same kind of thing happens:

```
C:\>go run chan.go
# command-line-arguments
.\chan.go:10: invalid operation: <-c (receive from send-only type chan<- int)
```

If I can't read from the channel, why bother writing to it? With that thought in mind, I figure I must be doing something wrong. I had the expectation that a send only `chan` would mean that one thread can only send while the other thread can only receive. This does not seem to be the case.

If I remove the `<-` entirely, it works, but that would make it bidirectional allowing the go routine to respond (even though it never does) and I'm looking to avoid that. It seems like I can banish numbers to a `chan` that I'll never be able to read from, or that I could read from a `chan` that's impossible to write to.

What I'm hoping to do is send integers from the main thread to the go routine for it to print using a one way channel. What am I doing wrong?

This is with go 1.3.3 on Windows if it matters. Updating to 1.4 didn't help. I might want to mention this is all x64 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Channel types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)
>
> A channel provides a mechanism for concurrently executing functions to
>   communicate by sending and receiving values of a specified element
>   type. The value of an uninitialized channel is nil.
>
> ```
> ChannelType = ( "chan" | "chan" "<-" | "<-" "chan" ) ElementType .
> ```
>
> The optional <- operator specifies the channel direction, send or
>   receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional. A
>   channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by
>   conversion or assignment.

You can be explicit about channel direction by conversion or assignment. For example, by conversion,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Thread(r <-chan int) {
    for {
        num := <-r
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    s, r := (chan<- int)(c), (<-chan int)(c)
    go Thread(r)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        s <- i
    }
    for len(c) > 0 {
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread :  1
Thread :  2
Thread :  3
. . .
```

Or, equivalently, by assignment,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Thread(r <-chan int) {
    for {
        num := <-r
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    var s chan<- int = c
    var r <-chan int = c
    go Thread(r)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        s <- i
    }
    for len(c) > 0 {
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way that works. This make me wonder why the compiler would allow me to create a one directional chan directly though.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: See my revised answer.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that in a particular exchange of data via an unbuffered channel, always one end is a writer and another end is a reader. If you were to try writing a client/server communication, sending a request one way then a response the other on the *same* channel (i.e. a truly bidirectional channel), you would probably get deadlocks when other clients tried to join in.

Comment: Therefore, it is best in practice to think of channels as unidirectional, even though they are loosely described as bidirectional in the spec. They can behave in more complex ways when they are buffered, but as a starting point I always reason about unbuffered channels being unidirectional only.

Comment: @peterSO makes the helpful illustration of passing a channel end into `func Thread(r <-chan int)` using the arrow notation. This arrow notation is good practice because the compiler will helpfully check correct usage of the channel end when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Go allows to create send- or receive-only channels like `c := make(<-chan int)`, however, I haven't came across a use case. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2431) in github.

About the error in the code;

```
func Thread(c chan<- int) {
    for {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Function parameter `c` can only be sent to. Attempting to receive from c will result in a compiler error but the line `num := <-c` tries to receive.

At the end, fixed version;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Thread(c <-chan int) {
    for {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    go Thread(c)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    for len(c) > 0 {
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Thread` function is passing a send-only channel, instead of a receive-only channel. But you don't need to `make()` it receive-only, you can pass a bidirectional channel to a goroutine as receive-only.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Thread(c <-chan int) {
    for {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println("Thread : ", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    go Thread(c)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    for len(c) > 0 {
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}
```

You can verify this by adding the line

```
c <- 3
```

in your `Thread` function, throwing the error `prog.go:11: invalid operation: c <- 3 (send to receive-only type <-chan int)`

See https://play.golang.org/p/5KNPNLqA_k